# How to add a class to a KendoUI Grid for angular2+ component base element?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there a way to easily add a class to a KendoUI Grid (for styling purposes)? So far I have tried using class and [ngClass] attributes, but it doesn't work.

```
<kendo-grid class="myClass" [ngClass]="'myNgClass'" ...>
```

outputs

```
<kendo-grid class="k-widget k-grid" ng-reflect-klass="myClass" 
    ng-reflect-class-name="k-widget k-grid" ...>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JWK9DvKoSiPm5XtbNNCI?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is known issue with current implementation. Both `class` and `ngClass` should work on host element. We will address it shortly.

As a temporary workaround you could wrap the `Grid` component in another element and cascade the rules through that element.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I've done for the moment. I didn't find a corresponding issue on your github, should I open one there and ask for deletion of the SO question?

Comment: You don't have to. It is already fixed and the package with the fix will be published shortly.